# How to resize window after adding nodes

Tags: java, javafx, resize, window

I'm looking for an easy way to resize a window after adding children to a Scene.

the Scene is already set on Stage and after I click a button I add another textfield to the scenen. This works fine, but if i add too many textfields, they will be out of Screen because the window is not updated.

I also tried to reset the Scene like that, but it did not help (I'm in Controller class here, root is the root-Element of the current Scene).

```
stage.setScene(root.getScene());
```

However, if I write the following code after adding the childs, it works, but you can see that the window is closed and opened which is very unsmooth. :/

```
stage.close();
stage.show();
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you try [`stage.sizeToScene()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--)?

Comment: lol, completly missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

or use setWidth and setHeight

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.show();

stage.setWidth(1024);
stage.setHeight(768);
```